# Rules to redirect in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have old urls to my news like http://example.com/mynew/35/this-is-the-title, where 35 is the Id of the news. Now my new urls is like http://example.com/mynew/this-is-the-title
I have no idea how get a redirect to all old news url to new urls. Any idea? Thanks

In my routes.php in codeigniter I have:

```
$route['news'] = 'news/index';
$route['news/(:num)'] = 'news/index/$1';
$route['mynew/(:any)'] = 'news/mynew/$1';
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `this-is-the-title` is a parameter of the `mynew` index() function? In which case just test if the first parameter e.g. 35 is an integer, if so get the second parameter and use that for your query.

Comment: Further, do you want to actually redirect or just have the same url but route it differently? Because you tagged htaccess and you provided routes so I'm not sure which you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `http://example.com/mynew/35/this-is-the-title` you've id of the table and you can easily find it through. But if you use this `http://example.com/mynew/this-is-the-title` there is no any unique identifier so you can't retrieve data from the table.

To archive this, you can do these

1. Alter table with URL slug( column name`url_slug` or `slug`)
2. create common controller method. As per your code `index()` under `news`(controller name)
3. create common news view

---

> **Note: Slug should contain unique text identifier to identify the exact news(same like the primary key)**

```
Title - this is an news title regarding php
slug - regarding-php
```

---

**In Controller**

```
public function index($slug)
{
    if (!empty($slug)) {
        # code...
        #write select code and load the common view
        $data['title'] = "my Heading" ;
        $data['content'] = "my para............." ;
        $data['footer'] = "foot" ;

        $this->load->view('news/common',$data);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

**In View**

```
 # echo will also work

<div id="title"><?= print_r($title); ?></div>
<div id="content"><?= print_r($content); ?></div>
<div id="footer"><?= print_r($footer); ?></div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is at all what the user is asking, I believe they already have this type of system in place and just want to fix the routes to support legacy urls where the url structure was slightly different.

Comment: there is no way to use route when its calling through id. unless he hard code all id to route

Comment: Yes. I've solved controller and view. What I need is to redirect 301 specially thinking in google. So when clic in http://example.com/mynew/35/this-is-the-title redirect to http://example.com/mynew/this-is-the-title