# About Slugs Creation in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Hello Every Every One here me.
 Actually me trying one thing from many days it about URL means me want friendly Url in my site Besides showing id etc there.Like (www.abc.com/this-is-me-from-php-show-test) in replacement of this (www.abc.com/controller_name/function/23) kindly help me as soon as possibly by badly i have no written code for you guys.just suggest me any site or tutorial about it.both suggestions appreciated dynamic slugs or static.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rules to redirect in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605464/rules-to-redirect-in-htaccess)

Comment: this is not as i want its simple send data from one to an other

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table called `projects` and currently it is identified by the `id` field e.g. `localhost/projects/get/123` then you should create another column in that table for `slugs` where you put the `name-of-the-project`. Then in your `get($slug)` function instead of querying the `id` field for the specific project query the `slug` field.

You can use a 3rd party library to generate slugs: https://github.com/ericbarnes/CodeIgniter-Slug-Library/blob/master/Slug.php

Then just write a script to populate all of the slug fields and it might be a good idea to test if the $slug field is an integer indicated a legacy id for current SEO purposes (to prevent broken links).